# What does the Cross-Platform Rating on PassMark mean? What kind of performance does it reflect?

Tags: processor, ryzen

What does the Cross-Platform Rating in a Price performance comparison page of a CPU on [PassMark](https://www.passmark.com/) mean? What kind of performance does it reflect? It seems the kind of performance it reflects is more like what Average CPU Mark does, which is basically multi-core performance. If so, what is the difference between these 2 numbers?

More specifically in my case, I am comparing these 3 CPUs to decide which one to buy: [AMD Ryzen 7 3800X vs AMD Ryzen 9 3900X vs AMD Ryzen 9 3950X](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/AMD-Ryzen-7-3800X-vs-AMD-Ryzen-9-3900X-vs-AMD-Ryzen-9-3950X/3499vs3493vs3598). The CPU Mark of the 3900X is lower than 3/2 of that of the 3800X, while the Cross-Platform Rating of the 3900X is higher than 3/2 of that of the 3800X. I am going after multi-core performance, so I am wondering whether the 3900X gives me 3/2 of multi-core performance compared to the 3800X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Passmarks own version log: https://www.passmark.com/products/performancetest/history.php

[image]

It's just that: a bunch of benchmarks cobbled together into a single score. Only the devs know how well these benchmarks scale to multiple threads, and how they weigh the individual results to condense them into a final score. So maybe don't focus too much on this.

Let's rather look at the CPUs themselves. A 3900X has a 50% higher core count compared to a 3800X. And it increases almost all CPU resources by at least 50%. Some shared resources like L3 cache even increase by 100%. If we stopped here, it would be safe to assume that the 3900X is 50% faster than the 3800X, at least in multi-threaded benchmarks with ideal scaling.
With 2 notable exceptions:
1) Thermal design power is the same. This causes the 3900X to run at lower clock speeds when all cores are loaded heavily. Dropping the performance increase to a bit less than 50%, at least if the user does not overclock.
2) Memory bandwidth. While the 3900X has almost double the write memory bandwidth compared to the 3800X (due to 2 chiplets vs. 1 and limited bandwidth from chiplets to the IO-die), the read memory bandwidth is practically the same. This causes less than 50% performance advantage in benchmarks (and applications) that become memory bandwidth limited at higher thread counts.

In conclusion: The 3900X can be nearly 50% faster than the 3800X in multi-threaded benchmarks and applications. But as always, it depends on the application.